# Best practice for creating a SDK for which also uses public available frameworks

Tags: c++, ios, c, ssl, openssl

Recently I'm having many issues with customers that is using our SDK, which also uses the exact public available framework/libraries that we use.  The issue is mainly duplicate symbols.

For example, one is Reachability which apple provides.  I solved that by adding a compile time prefix to the class.

However, another library for example OpenSSL Lib,  I'm have a hard time solving.

When compiling my SDK with these public libraries, how can I separate them into their own name spaces at compile time?  Or how do I make anything I do separate from what they will do with public libraries?

Thanks